# Remove characters from a string that are contained in another string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a scrabble game in Javascript.  Let's say I have a "rack" variable which contains seven letters, and a "word" variable which is the English-valid word I just spelled. I want to remove the letters from my rack that are contained in word.  How do I do this?

```
 let rack = "BOYCOTTS"
 let word = "BOY"
 remove(word, rack) 
 
 function remove(word, rack){ return(removed_string) }
```

This should return "COTTS" (with the "BOY" removed, but not every instance of B, O, Y, removed... just the number of instances that appear in the target string).

Comment: What you've tried so far ? can you please post the code you written from remove ? any particular problem you're facing or any thing you're not able to think of ?

Comment: Split them into array, remove items that match.

Comment: Share what you tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```js
const remove= (word, rack)=>rack.replace(new RegExp('['+word+']','ig'),'');

let rack = "BOYCOTTS", word = "BOY"

console.log(remove(word,rack));
console.log(remove('toy',rack));
console.log(remove('AID',rack));
```

I create a regular expression from the `word` by surrounding it with `[` and `]` and applying it globally (flag: `g`). This way all occurrences of the letters in `word` will be removed from `stack` when I use the regular expression in a `. replace(regexp,'')` call.

By applying a further flag `i` the regular expression is made case-insensitive, as you can see in the second call with `word='toy'`.

**EDIT**

OK, if you want to remove each letter only *once* you can do this:

```js
const remove= (word,rack)=>word.split('').reduce((a,c)=>a.replace(c,''),rack);

let rack = "BOYCOTTS", word = "BOY"

console.log(remove(word,rack));
console.log(remove('TOY',rack));
console.log(remove('AID',rack));
```

Comment: This doesn't work, unfortunately.  It removes *all* the instances of the letters in "BOY" from BOYCOTT.  The resulting string should read "COTTS."  Notice that the second "O" is removed from your example.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't realize that that was what OP wanted. I fixed my answer, please check again.

Comment: Forgive me for being obtuse, I'm completely new to Javascript, and I'm not sure what search terms to use to understand the syntax here.  What exactly is that function doing? I'm not sure what the arrow notation or purpose of the const function is.

Comment: Ahh, you can use the ES6 [fat arrow notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `fun=arg=>arg+1` as a short hand notation for `function fun(arg){return arg+1;}`.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the rack to an array and remove the first occurrence of each letter from it and then convert it back to a string with the following method.

```
function remove(word, rack) {
  const asArr = rack.split('');
  for (let letter of word) {
    // delete the letter from the rack
    const letterIndex = asArr.indexOf(letter);
    if (letterIndex > -1) {
      asArr.splice(letterIndex, 1);
    }
  }
  
  return asArr.join('');
}
```

To simplify this process, you might consider storing the rack exclusively as an array behind the scenes.

Comment: This will *not work* in cases where the letters in `word`are *not found* in `rack`. I. e. `console.log(remove('AID',rack));` will result in `BOYCO`.

Comment: true, didn't think about that